# How can I access the variables used in different cases of switch statement java?

Tags: java, menu, switch-statement

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pg3b {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int choice; 

do {

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  String name1="", name2="", character="", character1="";
  int level=0, level1=0;

  System.out.println("Please choose an option: \n1. Change Trainer1's name \n2. Change Trainer2's name \n3. Set Trainer1's Pokemon \n4. Set Trainer2's Pokemon \n5. Display the trainers' names and Pokemon \n6. Display the trainer who has the highest level Pokemon \n7. Exit the program"); 
  System.out.print("Choice: ");
  choice = keyboard.nextInt();

  switch(choice) {
    case 1: 
     System.out.println("Trainer1's name is currently Trainer1. Enter a new name: ");
     name1 = keyboard.next();
     System.out.println("Trainer1's name is now " + name1);
     break;
    case 2:
     System.out.println("Trainer2's name is currently Trainer2. Enter a new name: ");
     name2 = keyboard.next();
     System.out.println("Trainer2's name is currently " + name2);
     break;
    case 3:
     System.out.println(name1 + "'s Pokemon is currently Pokemon with level 0. Enter a new Pokemon and level: ");
     String input = keyboard.next();
     int inputLevel = keyboard.nextInt();
     character = input.substring(0);
     character = character.toLowerCase();
     level = inputLevel;

     boolean validPoke = true;
     boolean validLevel = true;

        if (level < 1 || level > 15) {
           System.out.println("Invalid level!");
           validLevel = false;
           }
        if (character.equalsIgnoreCase("bulbasaur")) {
           validPoke = true;
           }
        else if (character.equalsIgnoreCase("pikachu")) {
           validPoke = true;
           }
        else if (character.equalsIgnoreCase("charmander")) {
           validPoke = true;
           }
        else if (character.equalsIgnoreCase("squirtle")) {
           validPoke = true;
           } 
        else validPoke = false;
           System.out.println("Invalid Pokemon!");

        if (validLevel == true && validPoke == true) {
           System.out.println("Added level " + level + character + " for " + name1);
           }
       break;
   case 4: 
  System.out.println(name2 + "'s Pokemon is currently Pokemon with level 0. Enter a new Pokemon and level: ");
     String input1 = keyboard.next();
     int inputLevel1 = keyboard.nextInt();
     character1 = input1.substring(0);
     character = character.toLowerCase();
     level1 = inputLevel1;

     boolean validPoke1 = true;
     boolean validLevel1 = true;

        if (level1 < 1 || level1 > 15) {
           System.out.println("Invalid level!");
           validLevel1 = false;
           }
        if (character1.equalsIgnoreCase("Bulbasaur")) {
           validPoke1 = true;
           }
        else if (character1.equalsIgnoreCase("Pikachu")) {
           validPoke1 = true;
           }
        else if (character1.equalsIgnoreCase("Charmander")) {
           validPoke1 = true;
           }
        else if (character1.equalsIgnoreCase("Squirtle")) {
           validPoke1 = true;
           } 
        else validPoke1 = false;
           System.out.println("Invalid Pokemon!");

        if (validLevel1 == true && validPoke1 == true) {
           System.out.println("Added level " + level1 + character1 + " for " + name2);
        }
     break;   
   case 5: 
    System.out.println(name1 + character + level);
    System.out.println(name2 + character1 + level1);
  break;
   case 6:
    if (level > level1) {
     System.out.println(name1 + "has the highest level Pokemon.");
     }
    else if (level1 > level) {
     System.out.println(name2 + "has the highest level Pokemon.");
     }
 break;
 case 7:
     System.out.println("Quit");
     break;
  }
  }
  while (choice != 7);


}
}
```

How can I get the information defined in cases 1, 2, 3, and 4 to apply to case 5? Right now nothing shows up when you enter 5 into the menu. Also, currently when you enter a Pokemon and Level for cases 3 and 4, it says it's invalid even if it's correct. Does anyone know why and how I can fix it?

***By get the information in the other cases I mean that I have name1 defined in case 1, but I need to reference it again in case 5. Is there a way to do this without an error showing up saying that the variable cannot be found?

Also, sorry for asking more than 1 question in a post. I am new to Java and programming in general and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is your `Default` case ?

Comment: Declare all variable before the `switch-case` to use it in all cases.

Comment: This code looks like it probably has some copyright violations... but can you try to focus your question on one specific issue at a time and narrow your code down to just the code that applies to that issue?  Try recreating the problem with a minimal test case.

Comment: What do you mean by _"get the information defined in cases 1, 2, 3, and 4 to apply to case 5"_?  If you want some real help you will need to explain this much more clearly.  Also, you should generally ask only one question per post.

Comment: I wanna be the very best
Like no one ever was
To catch them is my real test
To train them is my cause

I will travel across the land
Searching far and wide
Each Pokemon to understand
The power that's inside

Answer (score 0):

When the program runs, each case is executed based on the value entered (for instance if the user enters 1 for choice, then only Case 1 is executed not the rest), this is because you have the break keyword at the end of each case, if you want all the case statements to run, you need to.
1. either remove `break` (which will mean that the user had no meaning choosing 1 as he will go through all options)
2. redesign, where you ask for relevant information beforehand or ask all necessary information in each case.

it would also be better if you declare the variables at the beginning of the method. since the values are being cleared every iteration (not sure if this was intentional)

IMHO, it would be nicer if you created more methods than writing long-winded case structure. it makes the code a little hard to read :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String name1="", name2="", character="", character1="";  int level=0, level1=0;
```

in this class all are local variable.So every while loop execution variable are reset so please declare outside the do whlie loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pg3b {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int choice; 

String name1="", name2="", character="", character1="";
  int level=0, level1=0;
do {

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

  System.out.println("Please choose an option: \n1. Change Trainer1's name 

 \n2. Change Trainer2's name \n3. Set Trainer1's Pokemon \n4. Set Trainer2's 

Pokemon \n5. Display the trainers' names and Pokemon \n6. Display the 

trainer who has the highest level Pokemon \n7. Exit the program"); 
  System.out.print("Choice: ");
  choice = keyboard.nextInt();

  switch(choice) {
    case 1: 
     System.out.println("Trainer1's name is currently Trainer1. Enter a new 

name: ");
     name1 = name1 + keyboard.next();
     System.out.println("Trainer1's name is now " + name1);
     break;
    case 2:
     System.out.println("Trainer2's name is currently Trainer2. Enter a new 

name: ");
     name2 = name2 + keyboard.next();
     System.out.println("Trainer2's name is currently " + name2);
     break;
    case 3:
     System.out.println(name1 + "'s Pokemon is currently Pokemon with level 

0. Enter a new Pokemon and level: ");
     String input = keyboard.next();
     int inputLevel = keyboard.nextInt();
     character = input.substring(0);
     character = character.toLowerCase();
     level = inputLevel;

     boolean validPoke = true;
     boolean validLevel = true;

        if (level < 1 || level > 15) {
           System.out.println("Invalid level!");
            validLevel = false;
           }
        if (character.equalsIgnoreCase("bulbasaur")) {
           validPoke = true;
           }
        else if (character.equalsIgnoreCase("pikachu")) {
           validPoke = true;
           }
        else if (character.equalsIgnoreCase("charmander")) {
           validPoke = true;
           }
        else if (character.equalsIgnoreCase("squirtle")) {
           validPoke = true;
           } 
        else validPoke = false;
           System.out.println("Invalid Pokemon!");

        if (validLevel == true && validPoke == true) {
           System.out.println("Added level " + level + character + " for " 

+ name1);
           }
       break;
   case 4: 
  System.out.println(name2 + "'s Pokemon is currently Pokemon with level 0. 

Enter a new Pokemon and level: ");
     String input1 = keyboard.next();
     int inputLevel1 = keyboard.nextInt();
     character1 = input1.substring(0);
     character = character.toLowerCase();
     level1 = inputLevel1;

     boolean validPoke1 = true;
     boolean validLevel1 = true;

        if (level1 < 1 || level1 > 15) {
           System.out.println("Invalid level!");
           validLevel1 = false;
           }
        if (character1.equalsIgnoreCase("Bulbasaur")) {
           validPoke1 = true;
           }
        else if (character1.equalsIgnoreCase("Pikachu")) {
           validPoke1 = true;
           }
        else if (character1.equalsIgnoreCase("Charmander")) {
           validPoke1 = true;
           }
        else if (character1.equalsIgnoreCase("Squirtle")) {
           validPoke1 = true;
           } 
        else validPoke1 = false;
           System.out.println("Invalid Pokemon!");

        if (validLevel1 == true && validPoke1 == true) {
           System.out.println("Added level " + level1 + character1 + " for 

" + name2);
    }
     break;   
   case 5: 
    System.out.println(name1 + character + level);
    System.out.println(name2 + character1 + level1);
  break;
   case 6:
    if (level > level1) {
     System.out.println(name1 + "has the highest level Pokemon.");
     }
    else if (level1 > level) {
     System.out.println(name2 + "has the highest level Pokemon.");
     }
 break;
 case 7:
     System.out.println("Quit");
     break;
  }
  }
  while (choice != 7);


}
}
```

Comment: i wrote the same before 22 min

Comment: You are an angel. Thank you sosososososoo much. I cannot even express to you how many tears were shed in my attempts to figure this out!